# Is there a way to search a TOvcFileViewer in OvcViewrof TurboPower Orpheus in Delphi

Tags: file, delphi, search

I have a program that will open and show a text file using TOvcFileViewer in OvcViewr.pas of TurboPower Orpheus. I want to know if there is a way to search the text or if I will have to load and search the file a different way?

```
procedure TForm1.Open1Click(Sender: TObject);  
begin
   if OpenDialog1.Execute then begin
    with Viewer8 do begin
      FileName := OpenDialog1.Filename;
      IsOpen := True;
    end;
end;
end;
```

Comment: What is Orpheus list viewer?

Comment: What is the component's exact name?

Comment: TOvcFileViewer in OvcViewr

Comment: Please make that clear in the question

Comment: -1 For deleting link to source. Do you want our help?

Comment: Sorry new to the site didn't know others could edit the original post for such things. I just saw something I had not added and deleted it.

Comment: -1 from me too for same reason. You should read the [FAQ] and learn how it works here.

Answer (score 1):

Use the public `TOvcFileViewer.Search` method.

From [OvcViewr.pas](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tporpheus/files/?source=navbar):

> ```
> function Search(const S : string; Options : TSearchOptionSet) : Boolean;
>   {-search for a string returning True if found}
>   override;
> ```

And from OvcData.pas:

> ```
> type
>   {Search option flags for editor and viewer}
>   TSearchOptions = (
>     soFind,        {find  (this option is assumed)        }
>     soBackward,    {search backwards                      }
>     soMatchCase,   {don't ignore case when searching      }
>     soGlobal,      {search globally                       }
>     soReplace,     {find and replace         (editor only)}
>     soReplaceAll,  {find and replace all     (editor only)}
>     soWholeWord,   {match on whole word only (editor only)}
>     soSelText);    {search in selected text  (editor only)}
>   TSearchOptionSet = set of TSearchOptions;
> ```

Comment: After looking at the code I am unsure what to use for the Options.